# Using custom fonts (non-MS Office) for Word VBA

Tags: vba

I have installed some custom Asian fonts in the Windows/Fonts folder. I am writing a code that reads some item names (just a plain string, ABC, but in Japanese) from MS-Excel cells, then pastes them in a text box in a new MS-Word document. The problem is that I can't use my custom fonts (these are `TTF` files) to format the text in MS-Word.

I tried to name the font with `.ttf` in the end, besides simply referring to its name as it appears in the drop-down menu in MS-Word.

```
Wrd_Doc.Shapes("shpTwo").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "ShigotoMemogaki Regular"
```

It refers to a text box named `shpTwo`. I pasted some text there and I want it to look like this custom font, named `ShigotoMemogaki Regular`. This font is saved in my Fonts folder, it works in MS-Word when I use it, but somehow the code does not recognize it, and instead, it uses the default Office Asian font, which is `MSMincho`.

So the text is clearly copied from MS-Excel, it is in the newly created text box in a new Word document, but it's not in the font I need.

Comment: The easiest way to figure out how to do this is to first make sure that Word can see your fonts (open a new document, select one of your fonts, type in some text to see that font working). Once you've done that, then using the same document, record a macro of selecting some text and changing the font to one of your custom fonts. Stop recording, and then open the macro dialog and edit the macro you just created. The code that Word generated is a good base for you to use in your own code.

Comment: Thank you. I see, your solution implies that somehow a blank new Word document created with VBA does not see the custom fonts, while a document in which I used a custom font will "know". Kind of a "vaccine". Hmmm, but that means I have to refer to a saved document, so I cannot create one from scratch. I will try that. But it is bizarre, the fact that the font is saved in Fonts, works properly in Word when used, has a clear name, but when I try to use that name VBA does not see it. I should add that I've been programming VBA for 10 years...but am new to Word. Best.

Comment: None of what you just wrote applies. The test with the new, blank Word document (created as usual from the Word menu) simply validates that the fonts are properly installed and available to Word. Recording the macro generates the code that you can copy/paste into your actual document and use as a basis for writing your own code. If you can record a macro that sets the font properly, you can use it in your code. If you can't, then the font is not properly installed and you need to resolve that issue before moving on to trying to use it in VBA.

Comment: I just tried your idea. Unfortunately it does not work. I opened a blank Word document. I turned on the macro recorder. Then I type some Japanese text, switching to a custom font. Clearly, the recorder identified the font name properly. But when I used that very font name in my original code, it failed to appear, still the default Office Asian font. Drives me crazy. Thank you anyway.

Comment: In which case, it remains that the font is not properly installed as you said. But what does that mean? It is in my Windows\Fonts folder, it appears in the drop-down menu in all Office applications. Does not that mean it is "properly installed"?

Comment: If it appears in the Word fonts menu, and a macro can record it and put the name in VBA code generated by recording that macro, it works, and will work in your own document. I can't tell you what you're doing wrong, because I can't see what you're doing. I can tell you I've used code generated by the macro editor literally hundreds of times to get information used in my own code without issues other than my own mistakes.

Comment: I fully agree with you, if it works with the macro recorder that it must work any other way. I found a solution, and it baffles me why it works. Here is the solution. I define the font name first. Then I insert the text. Then I define the font name again. Only like this it worked. It did not work defining the font first and adding the text next, or vice-versa. So I am happy it works, but surely something is wrong with Word.

Comment: Here is the code:

Comment: Wrd_Doc.Shapes("shpTwo").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "aoyagireisyosimo2"
Wrd_Doc.Shapes("shpTwo").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Second_Text
Wrd_Doc.Shapes("shpTwo").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "aoyagireisyosimo2"
Wrd_Doc.Shapes("shpTwo").TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 14

Comment: Right. Something is wrong with Word. It's only been around for a couple of decades, been used by literally billions of people, and because you can't get a font to work it must be Word that is defective. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your idea, it did help in the end.

Comment: Then how do you explain this?